# Crystal Reports Can Grow option for picture object

Tags: image, crystal-reports, report

I've got a crystal report built from v. 14.0.

Inside the report I've got a picture object that I've set the scaling properties to 33%.

The graphic location is set to pull from our DB.

I have two different images that I need displayed there depending on parameters passed into the report.

They are both 300 DPI, 1950 x 319.

Of both images, one pulls in wrong. It seems like it's scaling to 33% OF whatever 33% of the original image size is.  Basically looks like 1/3 of what it should look like.

The other image pulls in exactly how it should look @ 33% scaled.

The scaling doesn't change in the picture object properties when each image is loaded, it stays @ 33%.  If I change the one that comes in wrong to 100% scaled, then it looks correct which is weird, because @ 100% it should be way bigger.

I've tried copying the bad image into the good image and resaving but the same thing happens, the scaling gets set wrong.

I can't figure out what's different about the images that's causing this weird behavior.

I've tried saving the images to bmp format but the same thing continues to happen.  I've saved the images with multiple versions of photoshop and still nothing changes.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction here?  Thank you.

Comment: I can confirm after doing some resize testing in photoshop that the crystal report is scaling to 33% of (1950 x .33), scaling the width to 212 pixels instead of 644 pixels.  I don't understand why it's scaling twice for certain images.

Comment: I can't find anything online about CR scaling images twice so it must be something painfully obvious that I'm overlooking.

Comment: Created a new file 1950 x 319 in photoshop, using 300DPI.  Did not work.

Created a new file in paint, 1950 x 319 default DPI, it works.

Opened up the file created from paint using Irfanview to change the DPI to 300.  Re-saved and it stopped working.  I don't know how the old image is working with a 300 dpi yet the new ones don't.  This is so bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

After much research we've identified something in the exif info that is causing this issue.

There's a block in the image that doesn't work called app0 that contains the jpg file interchange format information.  I don't know a whole lot about it other than we used an app called photostudio.exe to look at the exif info.

We then used a tool called exiftool to remove that block from the exif info.

After doing so, the image scaled perfectly to 33%.

It's almost as if Crystal is scaling, then looking at that first app0 exif block and failing, then scaling again (effectively just retrying their method), and looking at the next blocks without failing any further.

Comment: http://www.stuffware.co.uk/photostudio/ link to photostudio app we used to see exif info.  Not that arcsoft photostudio.  It appears you can remove the jfif exif markers by going to Image > Markers > Remove and selecting the JFIF file markers.  Save the image from photostudio then reopen it to see that the markers are now gone.